# System verilog on Quartus synthesis issue

Tags: synthesis, synthesizer, system-verilog

```
module blockingbad(input logic clk,a,b,c,output logic y);
    logic x;

    always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    y=x|c;
    x=a&b;
    end
    endmodule
```

[image]

For the above Sysverilog snippet, the quartus 13.1 synthesizes a netlist shown above.

But when I interchange the ordering of calculation of y and x, I get a synthesized netlist shown below.

[image]

Why exactly am I getting a different netlist? I know it has got to do with the blocking assignment "=" but I can't understand the change in number of flip flops. Can anybody explain it to me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you type

```
y=x|c;
x=a&b;
```

it means that you want to calculate y = x|c, then you want to set x to a&b.  Since this must be implemented with gates, the old value of x must be stored until the end of the clock cycle, hence the extra flip-flop.  If you rewrote this with nonblocking assignments, you would do:

```
y<=x|c;
x<=a&b;
```

However, when you write

```
x=a&b;
y=x|c;
```

it means calculate x, then calculate y with the new value of x.  If you wanted to implement this with nonblocking assignments, you would do:

```
x<=a&b;
y<=(a&b)|c;
```

You could also use an assign statement to set x earlier, or mix a blocking and a nonblocking assignment.  In this case, if the registered x value is never used, the flip flop will be deleted automatically by the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only familiar with verilog, but in blocking assignments, the association is done sequentially. In the first case, y is associate to x|c, and it doesn't know yet that x = a&b, so it's not going to behave predictably, and that is probably what's causing the change in the number of ffs.

If you add x = a&b before y = x|c, then the compiler knows, again due to the sequential nature of blocking statements, that x= a&b, before it implements y = x|c.

Comment: No, it's actually perfectly predictable since the always block is clocked.  The extra flip-flop stores the value of x for one cycle so that the blocking statement evaluation is correct.